# How to check Dataframe for multiple empty columns?

Tags: python

I have a fairly large dataset containing several columns (over 100). I want to check which ones are completely empty so that they can be dropped.

I'm using this code `len(df.col_name.value_counts()) > 0` to plug in different columns to check but this is painfully slow. Is there a way I can check using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simply iterate through the columns; no need to name each one individually.

Most of your time is lost in building a new object from the vector expression.  Instead, use an `all` expression to evaluate the column, as this will stop checking when one of them fails to be empty.

Use the result of the `all` as a filter to your column deletion.

```
for column in df:
    if all(df[column].isnan()):
        del df[column]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be using for loops on pandas dataframes. They are built on numpy arrays, which can calculate array-wide operations much faster than that.

Instead, you want to use something like this:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.loc[:,~np.all(np.isnan(df), axis=0)]
```